# PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context for script

Tags: class, function, php

I've got problem:

I have a script that I'm working with and just upgraded to PHP 5.3.

In my kit_parser.php I'm getting the following fatal error:

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/sitename/public_html/secure/includes/hooks/kits/kit_parser.php on line 71

This is the section of code it's referencing:

```
LINE 71---> $this->kit__log_add(array("<b>PHP Warning</b> [$errno] $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile"));

    function kit_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $die = false) {
    if (1==1){//$this->displayErrors ) {
        switch ($errno) {
            /* Custom Errors */
            case E_USER_ERROR:
            break;
            case E_USER_WARNING:
            break;
            case E_USER_NOTICE:
            break;
            case E_ERROR:
                $this->kit__log_add(array("<b>PHP Error</b> [$errno] $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile"));
                die();
            break;
            case E_WARNING:
                $this->kit__log_add(array("<b>PHP Warning</b> [$errno] $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile"));
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Why is the error coming? Nothing found, never seen before in my other scripts. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: this is the code of a function or a class? is a static method?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that you're using `$this` in a `static` class method.  Make sure that the method this code is in is not `static`.  If it is, you should probably be using this syntax instead:

```
YourClassNameGoesHere::kit__log_add(array("<b>PHP Warning</b> [$errno] $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile"));
```

Comment: That's really hard to read and should probably go in your question.